# error con gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Estoy tratando de correr mi primera aplicación con django y gunicorn nesecito probar que todo este bien.

Después de hacer.
`python manage.py collectstatic`

Escribi:
`gunicorn --blind 0.0.0.0:8000 Proyecto.wsgi:application`

Y en consola cuando entro a la ip
Me da el siguente mensaje

```
[2022-01-01 20:55:12 +0100] [83138] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-01-01 20:55:12 +0100] [83138] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (83138)
[2022-01-01 20:55:12 +0100] [83138] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-01-01 20:55:12 +0100] [83140] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 83140               
[2022-01-01 20:56:05 +0100] [83138] [INFO] Handling signal: winch                                   
[2022-01-01 20:56:05 +0100] [83138] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
```

Pero la pagina en el navegador no carga

Comment: El navegador está en la misma máquina que el servidor? ¿Qué URL pones en el navegador? Cuando dices que no carga te refieres a que agota un tiempo de espera y el propio navegador da error, o a que el servidor responde un código de error como 404  o 500?

Comment: por fin me di cuenta de mi error. Estaba trabajando en un vps y no avía avierto el puerto 8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has intentado abrir el puerto 8000. Dependen de donde estés intentando esto